# How do I convert a column to Pandas Timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, type-conversion

I have a column in my DataFrame with values like `'2022-06-03T00:00:00.000Z'` and I want to convert these (in place) to `pd.Timestamp`. I see many answers he on how to convert to `np.datetime64` and on how do convert arbitrary columns of DataFrames, but can't figure out how to apply these to covering to `pd.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from pd.to_datetime method
I think this solve your problem
Just you need to active utc argument in your method

```py
import pandas as pd
 
lst = {'a':['Geeks', 'For'],'b':['2022-06-03T00:00:00.000Z','2024-03-03T00:00:00.000Z']}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df['b']=pd.to_datetime(df['b'],utc=True)

type(df['b'][0])
```

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edit my answer. I hopefull it is usefull for you

Comment: Actually it looks like `utc=True` isn't required.

Comment: I think your data is in timezone format. Sorry

Comment: I thought so too, but it's certainly `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`. Possible due the format ([ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with timezone info, apparently) of the original string values, e.g., `'2019-05-03T18:18:13.683Z'`